# Fixing broken XAMPP installation on MacOS

Tags: macos, xampp

I downloaded the [XAMPP .dmg installer](https://www.apachefriends.org/xampp-files/7.2.5/xampp-osx-7.2.5-0-vm.dmg) and copied XAMPP.app from it into my Applications folder. The first time I ran it a window popped up notifying me that additional files needed to be copied the first time so that XAMPP can run. I proceeded, but was immediately hit with a stack error due to insufficient disk space. I then freed up plenty of space and tried again, but XAMPP is not having any of it. I get **Error starting "XAMPP" stack** every time.

```
failed to start machine: hyperkit: [ERROR] Found a reference to cluster 9729 outside the file (max cluster 9728) from cluster 7621.2165
hyperkit: [ERROR] Mirage block device raised exception: Qcow.Make(Base)(Time).Reference_outside_file(_, _)
Mirage-block error: Block device is disconnected
Could not open mirage-block device: Invalid argument
Could not open backing file: Invalid argument
```

The setup process is only offered the first time the app is launched, and deleting/reinstalling the .app file does nothing because apparently some data remains on my system telling XAMPP that it has been launched before (and presumably does not need to be set up)... although the setup was never completed. I can find no application data for XAMPP in `~/Library` or `/Library`. Where does this phantom data reside, and how can I correct my XAMPP installation? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default download button for Macs points to [XAMPP-VM](https://www.apachefriends.org/blog/new_xampp_20170628.html), which runs the Linux version of XAMPP in macOS virtually. This is not what I wanted.

[image: Mac download button points to XAMPP-VM, not XAMPP]

I assume there is a way to get XAMPP-VM to work, but that is beyond the scope of this issue.

The solution in my case was to follow the "Click here for other versions" link and select a non-VM installer from the list.

[image: List of XAMPP and XAMPP-VM installers]